# Why is there a white screen before the actual launch screen appears in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, launch-screen

I created a flutter app and then added a launch screen with XCode by using a storyboard. My launch screen contains a background image that is aligned to the bottom and a centered logo. Now every time I start the app, there is a white screen before the actual launch screen appears. This is my LaunchScreen.storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14490.70" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14490.49"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Ydg-fD-yQy"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="xbc-2k-c8Z"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" image="LaunchImage.Background" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="YRO-k0-Ey4">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="84" width="414" height="812"/>
                            </imageView>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="LaunchImage.Center" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="m2E-Yf-1dK">
                                <rect key="frame" x="79" y="431" width="256" height="34"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="centerX" id="1a2-6s-vTC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="bottom" id="4X2-HB-R7a"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="leading" id="7gX-RD-p4w"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" secondAttribute="trailing" id="SGD-Ee-rA9"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="m2E-Yf-1dK" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Uz2-O6-cFf"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="m2E-Yf-1dK" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="centerX" id="f3e-ab-K73"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="76.811594202898561" y="251.11607142857142"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="LaunchImage.Background" width="375" height="812"/>
        <image name="LaunchImage.Center" width="256" height="34"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

I tried to figure out why this white screen is showing before the actual launch screen and I tried many things suggested in other stackoverflow questions but to no avail. Right now I do not have a clue.

Comment: Check this https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app.html and your good to go.

Comment: I don't think that this answers my question. This article describes how to replace the default blank white launch screen of a flutter app. I already did this by customizing the LaunchScreen.storyboard. But before this customized launch screen shows, there is a blank screen visible for a second or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue myself, it turns out to be a caching issue. With

```
flutter clean
```

and erasing the device settings and contents on iOS simulator, the white screen disappeared.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, exactly fixed it!

Answer (score -3):

** It's possible that your IP address will automatically update - so make sure that IP address when you run `npm run serve` matches the one in your `capcitor.config.json`

Comment: Sorry but this is not an answer to the question. My question has nothing to do with npm.